# zsh script is no longer working to update npm packages

Tags: zsh

I have used this script to update npm packages for a bunch of projects in a folder.

Today I tried (first time since apple has upgraded to zsh in their terminal) and it's not working.

```
for d in *; do if [ -d "$d" ]; then ( cd $d && pwd && npm update --save && git add . && git commit -m "package.json updates" && git push origin master ) fi done
```

This is the error I get:

```
zsh: parse error near `done'
```

Does anyone have any idea why its no longer working?

Thanks

Comment: Semicolon missing between fi and done?

Comment: @Matze That worked... I feel a bit stupid now because I tried a few different things like that with a semicolon and nothing worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comment, there is a semicolon missing. So this should work:

```
for d in *; do if [ -d "$d" ]; then ( cd $d && pwd && npm update --save && git add . && git commit -m "package.json updates" && git push origin master ) fi; done
```